# Did I activate everything (before I go home today)?

Tags: abap

What fast and reliable ways are there to know whether I activated everything I changed in the ABAP workbench?

Reason for asking: if I forgot something, I'm the reason that a (test) transport can't be exported (easily).

My closest approach to an answer is

1. change some arbitrary code
2. activate that code
3. If there was something left to activate, I'm offered to activate that, too.

But is there a fast and reliable way to do that without changing some arbitrary code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SE80 -> Environment -> Inactive Object will give you the list you are looking for.